# File cannot be downloaded error when exporting to xlsx using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, xlsx

Good Morning.

I need help regarding exporting data to XLSX format.

I always get this message box error message:

```
<IP Address> - download.phpをダウンロードできません。
```

Which says that the download.php cannot be downloaded.

On the other hand, when I try to change this to XLS format, I was able to download the file correctly.

here is my simple code:

**index.php**

```
<script>
function ExportDataTemplate()
{
    window.location = "download.php";
}

</script>

<input type="button" class="MyButton" value="Data With Template" style="width: 150px;" onClick="ExportDataTemplate();"/>
```

**download.php**

```
<?php
include 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_NOTICE);

ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
set_time_limit (0) ;

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007"); 
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("Templates/tl_export_xlsx.xlsx");

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('ＭＳ Ｐゴシック')->setSize(10);

$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$newFilename = "TL_Export_". date("YmdHi").".xlsx";

$styleArray = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'allborders' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
    )
  )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:C1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

$worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 2, "1");
$worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 2, "Department");
$worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, 2, Team Leader");

unset($styleArray);
ob_clean();

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$newFilename."\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007'); 
$objWriter->save('php://output');

?>
```

Thank you in advance.

By the way, I am using Linux Cent OS,
PHPExcel v1.7.6 and
PHP 5.3.3

Answer (score 1):

You have simple typo in your code. This:

```
$worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, 2, Team Leader");
```

Should be this:

```
$worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, 2, "Team Leader");
```

After that, everything seems to work properly.

**EDIT:**

Because you have IE 8, you should try resolving known compatiblity issues:

1. Try setting `Content-Type` to `application/vnd.ms-excel`
2. Try setting filename in `Content-Disposition` **without** quotes or with single quotes

Also, if you're using javascript (eg. `window.open`) to download XLSX file in IE 8, then the file may not be downloaded as XLSX is considered "not displayable" in browser.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem still occurs after changing it. actually, I also tried just loading the template and then output it. still I get the same problem.

Comment: @Joey, what web browser you're using?

Comment: The browser we are using Sir is IE 8.

Comment: @Joey, I've updated my answer above. See if it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. When I tried what you suggested, I just got a white screen. When I checked the error log for any relevant error, I was surprised that there was none.

Comment: @Joey, when you download XLS file (**not** XLSX), is it displayed in browser window or is it written to some folder on disk?

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. The download function is now working. Apparently, there had been some problems with the previous server. When we move it to a new one, it was OK.